# How to Parse data using unix shell script

Tags: unix

I have to parse data which is present in txt file using shell script and here is how the data is {"ABC":"ABC1234"}. I just want the ABC1234 as the out. Can you please help. I am not to scripting .

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '{"ABC":"ABC1234"}' |  cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
MBP:~ jhartman$ echo '{"ABC":"ABC1234"}' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*"\(.*\)".*/\1\2/g'
ABCABC1234
```